# Airport Extreme (5th gen) throttling ethernet internet speeds

Tags: imac, airport, performance, internet, ethernet

I purchased the router in 2012, and am experiencing slower speeds than expected from my Airport Extreme.

Brand new 16x4 channel DOCsis3 modem on Time Warner's approved list. 200 Mbps plan, and getting 225 down when connected from iMac directly to modem.

Then, bring the Airport into the mix and connect it to the modem via CAT6. Another CAT6 cable from Airport to iMac, and speeds drop to 93 Mbps.

I feel like the router should be able to handle that full 225 from the modem and more. Only other things connected to router are a few WIFI devices such as iPhone and printer. Playing with the radio modes, N only, etc., under WIFI doesn't change anything.

Is my Airport defective with this speed being measured?

Comment: What speed is negotiated between the AirPort Extreme and the Cable Modem? Are either router (cable/airport) in bridge mode? Unless it's gigabit, you may have your answer there. Secondly, what speeds do you get iMac over WiFi vs iMac over ethernet (both to the Airport) Lastly, gather the TX Rate, PHY and MCS from the iMac if you are connecting wirelessly to the Airport.

Comment: Thanks bmike, I'll need to gather some of this info after I get home from work. Not sure what "negotiated between the AirPort Extreme and the Cable Modem" means.

I haven't changed any settings on modem from out of box. Airport is in DHCP and NAT mode. It is gigabit ethernet, according to marketing tech specs.

Speeds are same over WIFI as ethernet, both clocking at 93 Mbps down through Airport. No difference, really.

Comment: Do you have another machine with gigabit you can test to see LAN transfer speed? According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPort_Extreme, your 5th Gen should support gigabit. Are you shutting your wifi off during these tests? That router doesn't support ac wifi, so you'll be capped on the wifi transfer limits.

Comment: Thanks, I turned off WIFI on my iMac, but not the router. I'll try that as well as LAN tests with 2 gigabit cpus. Anyone recommend software to test LAN speeds? 

802.11n should still be able to achieve 200 Mbps, no?

Comment: Update: I tested LAN speeds over ethernet, to a MacBook Air via thunderbolt ethernet adapter. Wrote a 200 MB packet from the iMac to the MacBook. Write speeds were much slower, but read speeds were 750 Mbps – that implies Gigabit is working over LAN? Still no success increasing speeds from the modem > APE > iMac over ethernet, it's getting capped around 93 Mbps. Last night I plugged the iMac directly into modem and it's back up to 225 Mbps down. For fun I turned on Internet sharing and connected the MacBook Air over the new wifi network. Was cranking 150 Mbps down. Hardware issue with Airport?